# Array of structures outside main - Go

Tags: go

I've working with a REST framework (https://github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest) and I'm trying to store an array of objects.

```
type Item struct {
        Name string
}

// I want to create an array of Items

func Add(w *rest.ResponseWriter, req *rest.Request) {
        data := Item{}
        err := req.DecodeJsonPayload(&data)
        if err != nil {
                rest.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                return
        } 
        // I want to append the new Item object to the array of items
        w.WriteJson(&data) 

}

func main() {
        handler := rest.ResourceHandler{
                EnableRelaxedContentType: true,
        }
        handler.SetRoutes(
                rest.Route{"POST", "/add", Add},
        )
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", &handler)
}
```

I'm unsure as to how to instantiate an array of Items outside of main(). If using a global array is not the best practice, what would be it? The examples provided by the framework featured a global map but in my use case, I cannot have a unique key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using a mutable global array as `Add` is probably called concurrently by your REST API package and therefore access to the global array must be synchronized.

What you could do is to write a routine that handles the items for you and communicates via a channel ([example on play](http://play.golang.org/p/MEppmO6RvZ)).

You would have the structure holding your data locally:

```
type ItemHolder struct {
    items   []Item
    Input   chan Item
    Request chan ItemRequest
}
```

and a goroutine which accepts new data or answers requests for insight of the current data:

```
func (i *ItemHolder) Run() {
    for {
        select {
        case req := <-i.Request:
            eq.Items <- i.items
        case in := <-i.Input:
            i.items = append(i.items, in)
        }
    }
}
```

This you would instantiate as a global variable since it is safe to do so:

```
var itemHolder = &ItemHolder{
    Request: make(chan ItemRequest),
    Input: make(chan Item),
}
```

Usage is straight forward, putting new things in equals putting a value in the `Input` channel
of the `itemHolder`:

```
func Add(i int) {
        var i Item
    // Your code filling i
    itemHolder.Input <- i
}
```

Requesting the current state of items means giving the `itemHolder` a channel to put the current
items in to.

```
func PrintCurrentItems() {
    rchan := make(chan []Item)
    itemHolder.Request <- ItemRequest{rchan}

    fmt.Println("current items:", <-rchan)
}
```

Obviously at some point you have to start the `itemHolder`:

```
func main() {
    go itemHolder.Run()

    ListenAndServe(/* ... */)
}
```

This way you have stored your items safe for concurrent access but are still able to access them globally.

Comment: What you say does make sense but it introduces concepts I'm not quite familiar with. I'll go through http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels for more information but your method seems much safer and better. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it but this works

```
type ItemSet struct {
    Items []*Item
}

var store ItemSet

..

store.Items = append(store.Items, &data)
...
```

Comment: You could also just have `type Items []*Item`

Comment: That seems much cleaner. I'll check that out and get back to you

Comment: @elithar - thanks very much for that neater way of initialising. Very good for sampling the language and its capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Each HTTP request runs in its own Go Routine. If you want to store the items in a global data structure then you'll have to protect the access using a lock.

Here is the relevant example from the documentation:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/rest"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    api := rest.NewApi()
    api.Use(rest.DefaultDevStack...)
    router, err := rest.MakeRouter(
        rest.Get("/countries", GetAllCountries),
        rest.Post("/countries", PostCountry),
        rest.Get("/countries/:code", GetCountry),
        rest.Delete("/countries/:code", DeleteCountry),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    api.SetApp(router)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", api.MakeHandler()))
}

type Country struct {
    Code string
    Name string
}

var store = map[string]*Country{}

var lock = sync.RWMutex{}

func GetCountry(w rest.ResponseWriter, r *rest.Request) {
    code := r.PathParam("code")

    lock.RLock()
    var country *Country
    if store[code] != nil {
        country = &Country{}
        *country = *store[code]
    }
    lock.RUnlock()

    if country == nil {
        rest.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }
    w.WriteJson(country)
}

func GetAllCountries(w rest.ResponseWriter, r *rest.Request) {
    lock.RLock()
    countries := make([]Country, len(store))
    i := 0
    for _, country := range store {
        countries[i] = *country
        i++
    }
    lock.RUnlock()
    w.WriteJson(&countries)
}

func PostCountry(w rest.ResponseWriter, r *rest.Request) {
    country := Country{}
    err := r.DecodeJsonPayload(&country)
    if err != nil {
        rest.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    if country.Code == "" {
        rest.Error(w, "country code required", 400)
        return
    }
    if country.Name == "" {
        rest.Error(w, "country name required", 400)
        return
    }
    lock.Lock()
    store[country.Code] = &country
    lock.Unlock()
    w.WriteJson(&country)
}

func DeleteCountry(w rest.ResponseWriter, r *rest.Request) {
    code := r.PathParam("code")
    lock.Lock()
    delete(store, code)
    lock.Unlock()
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

Also 'ResourceHandler' is deprecated, you may want to use the v3 API.

Antoine - go-json-rest author

Answer (score 0):

You could use [The Init function](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init), which is called with `func init() {...}`. It is a function that is called before `main()` and according to the docs:

`Finally, each source file can define its own niladic init function to set up whatever state is required. (Actually each file can have multiple init functions.) And finally means finally: init is called after all the variable declarations in the package have evaluated their initializers, and those are evaluated only after all the imported packages have been initialized.
Besides initializations that cannot be expressed as declarations, a common use of init functions is to verify or repair correctness of the program state before real execution begins.`

Comment: Couldn't you just instantiate the array outside the function? What would be the advantage with the init()?

Comment: Init is guaranteed to be called as the very last step before `main()` begins, so if your Item struct requires something to have been imported and instantiated it is possible that it could fail if you try to initialize it outside of `init()`. So the advantage is that you know that by the time `init()` runs, everything you've imported is ready for use.

Comment: Ah, so main() is the only guarantee that all the imports have been completed? That's very useful! I'm very new to Go (2 hours).